# If I change my CPU to i7 will I have to reinstall windows?

Tags: windows-10

Everything else is the same. I just want to change CPU

Also I used bitlocker

Will that affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows will see and use the new CPU. If you made msconfig CPU core "tweaks", undo them otherwise you limit the usable cores.

Comment: source? What about motherboard?

Comment: I downgraded an AMD Phenom X4 to an Athlon X4 because the Phenom was faulty and Windows worked fine. If the motherboard is also changed, Windows should boot if the boot drive uses the same type (nvme, AHCI, IDE). Windows will reinstall the other drivers. But you should also do a full backup of your Windows.,

Comment: windows don't ask to reactivate license?

Comment: for CPU only, no. If you also change the motherboard, yes